# WPF DataTemplate Trigger binding from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm constructing `DataTemplates` for a ListView in the code behind, since the number of columns is unknown at the moment of binding. My method for adding columns into a `ListView`:

```
    private void FillListView(DataTable table)
    {
        GridView grid = (GridView)lvMain.View;
        var template = FindResource("cellTemplate");

        foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
        {

            var gridColumn = new GridViewColumn()
            {
                Header = col.ColumnName,
                DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(col.ColumnName)
            };

            gridColumn.CellTemplate = template;
            gridColumn.CellTemplate.Triggers.Add(mouseOverTrigger);
            gridColumn.CellTemplate.Triggers.Add(mouseNotOverTrigger);

            grid.Columns.Add(gridColumn);
        }
        lvMain.ItemsSource = ((IListSource)table).GetList();
    }
```

Those triggers never fire. I assume it can be done with text factories, added into a template, but in this case I don't know how to create a property trigger programmatically.

How can I make `DataTemplates`, created from code behind, to react to `IsMouseOver` changes?

**UPD:** I've moved the DataTemplate to the Resources and placed Triggers declaration there:

```
    ...    
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="cellTemplate" x:Name="cellTemplate">
            <TextBlock x:Name="cellTextBlock" Text="{Binding}"/>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="cellTextBlock" Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="cellTextBlock" Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                </Trigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <ListView x:Name="lvMain" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    ...
```

**UPD 2:** I'm wondering why, but the `template` declared just before loop gets applied in a way, I don't understand. If I add something weird in XAML code, for example, let the `DataTemplate` look like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="cellTemplate" x:Name="cellTemplate">
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="500"/>
            </Style>
        </DataTemplate.Resources>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            ...
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            <TextBlock>asdfasdfad</TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The given `template` IS applied to a column, but does not affect anything — neither `width` is 500, nor template consists of 2 `TextBlock`s with weird texts..

Comment: Actually, you don't need to create any data templates in code-behind in WPF. In your code, I don't see any data template creation by the way. I suppose your *actual* question is: how to bind a WPF's list view to a data table, right?

Comment: Gosh, I've erased an extra line from my question. Added it again. No, actual question is "How to make ListView cells to react on mouse events", and as far as I investiagted, the most simple thing is to use `DataTemplate`s and `Trigger`s

Comment: Your `ItemsSource` list view binding is incorrect. This is the core issue.

Comment: @dymanoid what's wrong with it? The data gets shown as it should.

Comment: Are you setting Background locally in your template as well via triggers? The local value would override any trigger.

Comment: I never touch any of properties locally, only via Triggers

Comment: @ArliChokoev: Your last XAML update should actually work. Did you try to move the mouse pointer over the `TextBlock`?

Comment: @mm8 Yes, with no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in my code is the way of column declaration:

```
    var gridColumn = new GridViewColumn()
    {
        Header = col.ColumnName,
        DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(col.ColumnName)
    };
```

`DisplayMemberBinding` has a higher priority than `CellTemplate`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.displaymemberbinding?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

You're currently trying to bind to `IsMouseOver` in the `DataContext`, rather than on the control. You need to add the source:

```
mouseOverTrigger.Binding = new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("IsMouseOver"), RelativeSource = RelativeSource.Self };
```

or use a `Trigger` rather than a `DataTrigger`

Comment: Alas, this doesn't work as well. By the way `Trigger` doesn't have `Binding` attribute. My first thought was also to use `Trigger` instead, but I coudn't find a way to link to the background of the `CellTemplate`

Comment: I've just edited my question and used `Trigger`s from XAML instead of `DataTrigger`s. They didn't fire as well. I've checked debugger, and they actually DO bind, but don't fire somehow.